# Forcing a line layer's geometry to conform to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have 2 line layers in QGIS representing rivers, type A and type B. I want to be able to merge them into a single rivers layer and populate an attribute telling me if they are of type A, type B or both. The resulting layer cannot have duplicate geometries.

The problem is that the layers were digitized using different basemaps and were then simplified using different thresholds. Therefore, the layers don't line up and one layer is more geometrically correct than the other.

I've included a diagram to illustrate what I mean. I need to keep the geometry of the red layer and snap the tributary shown in the purple box to it. The type attribute in the purple box should be "B", "A" in the green box and "Both" for the rest. [image]

I've tried to merge the layers then use v.clean but the resulting geometry is somewhere between the 2 layers.

Comment: You could try using the **Geometry Snapper** plugin which you can download/install from the menubar: `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`. You can set the red layer as the _reference layer_ and set a tolerence. Might work slightly better than `v.clean` :)

Comment: I should have said in my original question that I'm using QGIS 2.8.2 on a corporate system, so I'm unable to upgrade. That plugin is therefore not available to me.